# Use Promises in node js

Tags: node.js, promise, ejs, bluebird

I am new in nodejs. I have started learning nodejs. I want to use promises in nodejs. I have successfully installed bluebird.Cureently my code looks:

```
req.getConnection(function(err,connection){
  var query = connection.query('SELECT node_questions.question_name,node_questions.description FROM node_questions LEFT JOIN node_user ON node_questions.user_id=node_user.id;SELECT * FROM node_user ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5',function(err,rows)
        {

     var data =rows[0];
     var data2 = rows[1];
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data2);
             res.render('index', { page_title: 'Welcome',session:req.session.userId,email:req.session.email,data:data,data2:data2});
         });

    });
};
```

I want use promises here. How can I do.

Please help...

Comment: Why did you decide to you bluebird instead of native promises, just curious.

Comment: @torazaburo: More features, better docs, faster implementation… Do you really need to ask?

Comment: What module do `getConnection()` and `connection.query()` come from?  I need to look up some things about their API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Bluebird, you can use it's `.promisify()` method to make a promisified version of any asynchronous function that follows the nodejs calling convention.  In this case, you can do this:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var getConnection = Promise.promisify(req.getConnection, req);

getConnection().then(function(connection) {
    var query = Promise.promisify(connection.query, connection);
    return query('SELECT node_questions.question_name,node_questions.description FROM node_questions LEFT JOIN node_user ON node_questions.user_id=node_user.id;SELECT * FROM node_user ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5');
}).spread(function(rows, fields) {
     // process result here
     console.log("rows = ", rows);
     var data = rows[0];
     var data2 = rows[1];
     console.log(data);
     console.log(data2);
     res.render('index', {
         page_title: 'Welcome',
         session: req.session.userId,
         email: req.session.email,
         data: data,
         data2: data2
     });
}, function(err) {
     // process error here
});
```

---

Usually when you want to convert something to use promises, you can "promisify" your function just once in a module and then use that promisified version in the rest of the module like it shows above for the `getConnection()` function.  The `connection.query()` case is a bit unique because the `connection` object is a dynamically created object so you have to promisify it each time you create a new connection object.

While it is generally better to promisify each stage of the asynchronous operations (as I've done above) because it makes for cleaner and more consistent error handling and error propagation, you could also just wrap all the traditional callback stuff into one promise like this (though a robust implementation would need to catch exceptions internally too and turn them into rejected promises, but you can see the general idea here):

```
new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    req.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        var query = connection.query('SELECT node_questions.question_name,node_questions.description FROM node_questions LEFT JOIN node_user ON node_questions.user_id=node_user.id;SELECT * FROM node_user ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5', function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) 
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}).then(function(rows) {
     // process result here
     var data = rows[0];
     var data2 = rows[1];
     console.log(data);
     console.log(data2);
     res.render('index', {
         page_title: 'Welcome',
         session: req.session.userId,
         email: req.session.email,
         data: data,
         data2: data2
     });
}, function(err) {
     // process error here
});
```

Comment: @Karan - I don't know what you mean.  In the first code block, the `.then()` handler processes the result of the query.  Returning the `connection.query()` promise automatically chains it onto the prior promise and makes it's return value come out to the `.then()` handler as shown.

Comment: I means in .then() handler  it does not show anything means it does not come into .then handler.

Comment: @Karan -  Then put a `console.log(err)` where it says "process error here" and see what that says.  I don't have any ability to run this code to test it myself.  And, look in the console to see if any errors are showing.

Comment: [TypeError: undefined is not a function]

Comment: @Karan - Do you know what line of code the `TypeError` occurs on?  I've modified my first code sample to try things a slightly different way.

Comment: You might want to make sure the connection gets closed in all cases (error or not). See `using` in bluebird docs.

Comment: @ jfriend00 Now all data in "console.log(data)" this.

Comment: @ByteArcher - yes, that is required also.  That would have been required in the OP's code too, so I assume they must have just only posted part of their code.

Comment: when I console rows[0]...It shows like [ [ { question_name: 'What is Php}], [ { id: 1} ] ]. when I console rows[1] then shows [ [ { catalog: 'def',
      db: 'nodeDemo',
      table: 'node_questions',
      orgTable: 'node_questions'} ] ]

      name: 'question_name',

Comment: @Karan - I changed `.then()` to `.spread()` because `connection.query()` apparently returns two values, not just one like your code was showing so that affects how it gets promisified (a normal promise only returns one value).  I think that will sort out that part of that part of the confusion.

Comment: @Karan - Please note that you need to be closing your connections when you're done with them.

Comment: Call `promisifyAll` _once_, it will promisify the _prototype_ of connection. `promisifyAll` is a slow function.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Are you saying that you know that this particular library happens to work to promisifyAll the connection only once?  Since objects are not required to put all methods on the prototype, it is not guaranteed to work in all circumstances, right?  Is promisifyAll doing anything else the second time besides just iterating properties and seeing that everything is already in place?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - I changed it to only do a single `Promise.promisify(connection.query, connection)` which would be lighter weight.

Comment: Wrapping a callback naively into a promise has 2 pitfalls: the initiating function can throw exception that goes unnoticed, and the resulting callback can be called more than once leading to undefined behavior. More info: http://bytearcher.com/articles/pitfalls-of-promisifying-by-band/

Comment: @ByteArcher - Promisifying is not to be done blindly.  It does only work if the callback is only called once because promises are one-shot devices.  Are you saying that `connection.query()` will call its callback more than once?  That does not seem to be the case to me.  Also a good promisifying operation will wrap the function in try/catch and turn exceptions thrown by it into a rejected promise where they will be propagated like other errors (not go unnoticed) which is what Bluebird does with its promisify operations.  If doing robust manual promisifying, one would have to do that too.

Comment: @jfriend00 was referring to the latter part of your answer where you wrap promise by hand. But sorry my bad, the native `new Promise()` way of doing it does catch exceptions thrown inside the initiating function so all good in that regard.

Answer (score 2):

```
var promise = require('bluebird');

var getRows = function () {

   var deferred = promise.pending();

   var query = connection.query('SELECT node_questions.question_name,node_questions.description FROM node_questions LEFT JOIN node_user ON node_questions.user_id=node_user.id;SELECT * FROM node_user ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 5',function(err,rows) {
        if(!err) deferred.fulfill(rows);
        else deferred.reject(err.message);
   });

   return deferred.promise;
}
```

and you can call function like below;

```
getRows()
.then(function(rows) {
// make somethings with rows data here
})
.catch(function(err) {
   // you can get rejected data here
})
```

Comment: `promise.pending()` is deprecated.